# middle-click on svg use element open new tab

Tags: firefox, svg, xlink

With firefox, when I middle-click (or ctrl+click) on a `use` element, it open the `xlink:href` url in new tab (like a `href`)

bug or feature?

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 400 80">
    <circle id="circle" cx="40" cy="40" r="30" fill="#29e"></circle>
    <use xlink:href="#circle" transform="translate(70, 0)" style="stroke: red;"></use>
</svg>
<p>ctrl+click on right circle</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an [unresolved bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=847895) that they're not really sure how to handle. Trigger is the `xlink:href` that gets somehow internally treated just like an A.href does (middle-click or ctrl + click open to a new tab.)  One workaround is to bury the `xlink:href` element under an invisible rect:

```html
    <svg viewBox="0 0 400 80">
        <circle id="circle" cx="40" cy="40" r="30" fill="#29e" />
        <use xlink:href="#circle" transform="translate(70, 0)" style="stroke: red;" />
        <rect style="opacity:0" x="80" y="10" width="60" height="60" />
    </svg>
    <p>ctrl+click on right circle - nothing happens</p>
```

If you have any events that need to trigger, you'll have to tie them to the invisible rect.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround for the bug linked in previous answer you may also use `pointer-events: none` CSS rule on the `use` element:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 400 80">
    <circle id="circle" cx="40" cy="40" r="30" fill="#29e"></circle>
    <use xlink:href="#circle" transform="translate(70, 0)" style="stroke: red; pointer-events: none;"></use>
</svg>
<p>ctrl+click on right circle</p>
```

Or declare that all `use` elements must not be clickable with `<style>use{pointer-events: none;}</style>`.

Obviously, this workaround is applicable only in case the element has NOT to be interactive at all.